# Creating list content type using csom

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I am not able to create a list content type using the below snippet. It throws a **ServerException** with additional information - "**The site content type has already been added to this list.**"

```
       var list =  clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("sometitle");
       var documentCT = clientContext.Web.ContentTypes.GetById("0x0101");
       clientContext.Load(list,l=> l.ContentTypes);
       clientContext.Load(documentCT);
       clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

       var test = new ContentTypeCreationInformation(){
            Name = "TestCT", ParentContentType =documentCT };

       list.ContentTypes.Add(test);

       list.Update();
       clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Basically, I want to create a list content type whose parent is the "Document" CT.

Comment: The error that you are getting suggests that the content type has been created and is attached to the list, running it over and over will throw this error, are you saying you have run the script and the content type exists but does not attach to the list or the content type doesn't even get created?

Comment: yes, the content type is not created.

Comment: Where are you checking? site settings, content types?

Comment: yes in site content types.. Please note my objective is to add list content type...

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem.

What is happening here is that you have added the content type to the list successfully but you haven't turned on "allow management of content types" in Library settings > Advanced Settings > First setting. You will not see the content type via the UI.

Once you turn on this setting you will see your content type was in fact added.

Here's how I create a library

```
public static List CreateLibrary(ClientContext context, string title, bool allowContentTypes)
    {
        ListCreationInformation lci = new ListCreationInformation
        {
            Description = "Library used to hold Dynamics CRM documents",
            Title = title,
            TemplateType = 101,

        };

        List lib = context.Web.Lists.Add(lci);
        lib.ContentTypesEnabled = allowContentTypes ? true : false;
        lib.Update();
        context.Load(lib);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        return lib;

    }
```

For your case just add in the line:

```
list.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
```

Don't forget the list.Update(), I see you have it in your code but for anyone else, this part is essential before you use ExecuteQuery()